# Zurb Foundation 4 Columns not resizing

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I've got Zurb Foundation 4 setup in an example as per the instructions [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/rails.html).

When I create a basic page with one row and 3 columns with a width of 4 and I change the viewport (browser) size, the width of the columns do not change. They just stay at the static value of whatever it started at.

I was under the impression that it should 'just work' to scale the widths of the columns dynamically to be responsive to screen size.

Is there something I'm missing here?

[Here is the test application demonstrating my troubles.](https://github.com/jamesconant/foundation_test)

Answer (score 0):

Just dawned on me that the problem was that I was setting a fixed width on the body element. Ooops!